# Insert in table such that it does not create consecutive duplicates H2

Tags: sql, h2

I need to create insert query for H2 db. I need to insert in table such that it do not create consecutive duplicate in table and ignore it. For example,

```
First name | Last name | Date
A          |  Z        | 2018-12-02
B          |  Y        | 2018-12-03
A          |  X        | 2018-12-04
```

If I have to insert row `|  A  |  W  | 2018-12-01 in above table sorted in ascending order by date, it checks for consecutive duplicate in Firstname column. Since it create consecutive duplicate in table therefore it ignore it.

```
First name | Last name | Date
A          |  W        | 2018-12-01
A          |  Z        | 2018-12-02
B          |  Y        | 2018-12-03
A          |  X        | 2018-12-04
```

Answer (score 2):

In H2 you can use the following SQL:

```sql
INSERT INTO tableName SELECT * FROM VALUES ('A', 'W', DATE '2018-12-01') T(F, L, D)
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM tableName
        QUALIFY "First name" = F
        AND DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY "Date")
            - DENSE_RANK(D) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "Date") OVER() IN (-1, 0)
    );
```

Here the window version of hypothetical set `DENSE_RANK` function (don't mix it with window `DENSE_RANK` function, that's a different one) is used to determine the insert position of a new row:

```sql
DENSE_RANK(D) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "Date") OVER()
```

This aggregate function is a part of the SQL Standard, but in the SQL Standard in may not be used as a window function, but H2 is less restrictive.

Then the plain `DENSE_RANK` window function is used to number existing rows in the table. The difference between number of a row and number of a hypothetical row is -1 for row before the inserted row and 0 for row after the inserted row.

We need to check only rows with the same `"First name"` value. So the whole filter criteria will be

```sql
"First name" = F
    AND DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY "Date")
        - DENSE_RANK(D) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "Date") OVER() IN (-1, 0)
```

In the SQL Standard you can't filter results after evaluation of window functions, but H2 has non-standard `QUALIFY` clause (from Teradata) for that purpose, in other DBMS a subquery is needed.

The final condition to decide whether row may be inserted is

```sql
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM tableName
    QUALIFY "First name" = F
    AND DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY "Date")
        - DENSE_RANK(D) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "Date") OVER() (-1, 0)
);
```

If there are no such rows, insertion of a new row will not create two sequential rows with the same `"First name"` value.

This condition can be used in the plain standard insert from select command.

This solution is not expected to be fast if a table has many rows. A more efficient solution can use subqueries for lookups for previous and next rows such as `NOT EXISTS SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE "Date" > D ORDER BY "Date" FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY) UNION (SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE "Date" < D ORDER BY "Date" DESC FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY) WHERE "First name" = F`, but H2 doesn't allow references to outer tables from deeply nested queries, so `D` here needs to be replaced with JDBC parameter (`… VALUES (?1, ?2, ?3) … WHERE "Date" < ?3 …`). You can try to build such command by yourself.

Comment: This query will check for duplicate but it does not checks for consecutive duplicate. If I have to enter value in Firstname as 'B' it should allow but not for 'A'.

Comment: You want to insert a row if and only if there is no more than 1 row with the same value in `"First name"` column?

Comment: Yes it should not create consecutive records of A as shown above in table when sorted by date.

Comment: I've updated my answer, but this time it is for H2 only. Your task is quite complex to write a command that will work in multiple DBMS.